# The problem with converting ts files to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, linux

So I download ts files from h264.m3u8. The files look like this "https://.net/data/3/a/e/6d162b532610fdae/h264_00000005.ts ". I merge them into one common ts file. And I'm trying to get an mp4 file using ffmpeg. I execute the following command `sudo /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -y -f mpeg ts -i concat:/tmp/yLx1B9X9Mb/lujqnqQrtm.ts -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4.` After that, I get

```
ffmpeg version n3.1-1-g36fcb8c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libgsm --enable-libxvid --disable-static --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg
  libavutil      55. 27.100 / 55. 27.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 40.101 / 57. 40.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.102 /  6. 46.102
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] Could not detect TS packet size, defaulting to non-FEC/DVHS
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] probed stream 0 failed
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] nothing to probe for stream 1
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] probed stream 1 failed
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] probed stream 2 failed
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x1bc9540] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'concat:/tmp/yLx1B9X9Mb/lujqnqQrtm.ts':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0[0xfaf]: Unknown: none
    Stream #0:1[0x15]: Unknown: none
    Stream #0:2[0x15b4]: Unknown: none
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

The main problem is that it works for other ts files, but in this case it doesn't. I suspect that the whole problem is that there is a block with h264_init.mp4 here in m3u8, but to be honest I don't understand what I need to do with it.

It seems to me that I have already tried everything, but maybe I was doing it wrong

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of ffmpeg. Upgrade to 6.1 and try.

Comment: Thanks, but it works with this version too. I immediately merge it not into a ts file, but into an mp4 and after that ffmpeg -i h264_raw.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy h264.mp4